# No module name pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.10

I have installed pandas and using python3.10 under microsoft window os. I can import pandas in cmd line. But if import from my code, the no module named pandas comes out. What happens? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you most likely installed pandas with a different python version. Try importing pandas in cmd after running python3.10 (rather than simply 'python' and letting Windows resolve the version). If that works then also try running 'python3.10 .py'